# Pull info from a Related field within Matrix > within Super Table

Tags: matrix, relatedto, plugin-supertable

Ok, my mind is about to implode with this… any help on template syntax very welcome!

I have 2 Sections: ‘**artists**’ and ‘**schedules**’

In the ‘**schedules**’ section I have a Matrix field called ‘*stageSchedule*’, with a Block type called ‘*dayOfEvent*’

In that Block type I have a **Super Table** field called ‘*schedule*’. - breakdown....

- **schedules** (Section)
- - *stageSchedule* (Matrix) > *dayOfEvent* (Block)
- - - schedule (Block field (Super Table)) - ST

In ‘*schedule* (ST)’ I have a date field called ‘*timeOn*’, which is when the artist is due to be on stage. I thought I could get this information from ‘*schedule* (ST)’ by having an ENTRIES field called '***act***' (in the same ST field) which is linked to a specific artist from the ‘**artists**' section.

What I want to do... On the individual ‘Artist Bio’ pages I want to display what time they’re going to be on stage by pulling that information from ‘schedule > stageSchedule (M) > dayOfEvent (B) > schedule (ST) > ‘timeOn’.

I have tried every which way but I either get an error or nothing at all :/

I hope that makes sense... Thanks to anyone who can work this one out!

**EDIT**

As a test I created a Super Table field on it's own (not within Matrix)  and got the data correctly using this:

```
{% set reverseRelatedElements = craft.superTable.getRelatedElements({
    relatedTo: {
      targetElement: entry,
      field: 'testTimes.artist' // Super Table Field
    },
    section: 'schedules’
  }) %}

  {% for relatedEntry in reverseRelatedElements %}
    {{ relatedEntry.testTimes.timeon|datetime('H:i') }}
    {{ relatedEntry.testTimes.timeOff|datetime('H:i') }}
  {% endfor %}
```

So basically I need to do the same but target a Super Table field nested in a Matrix field?  Here's an image...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it yet but it should like this :

```
{% set entries = craft.entries().section('schedules').all() %}
{% for entry in entries %}
{% for block in entry.stageSchedule : %}
    {% if block.type == 'yourblocktype' : %}
         {% for item in block.schedule %}
            {{ item.timeOn }}
         {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I assume there is only one entry in schedules sections.
Please be remind block type is different with block name. 
Hope this help.

Comment: Hi @aodihis, there are more than one entries because there are more than one stages.  I have tried your solution as follows but I get an error (Key "stageSchedule" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist.).   {% set entry = craft.entries().section('shedules').all() %}
  {% for block in entry.stageSchedule %}
      {% if block.type == 'dayOfEvent' %}
           {% for item in block.schedule %}
              {{ item.timeOn|datetime('short') }}
           {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

Comment: @Martin , I see so we need to do a loop for each entry. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Hi @aodihis, thank you but I can't see how your solution is looking for the reverse relation with 'artist'?  ---  I have edited my post with more information if it helps?